# Call a radio button that is not selected

Tags: html, code-behind

I have a program/website. It has radio buttons in it and I am using VS 2015. I am using the code behind for aspx for the page_load. When a person select a radio button, I use Request["radiobuttonname"] to get the value that the user selected.

My question is, how do I get the value of a radio button that is not selected. For example, I have a radio button for Yes, NO, I'D RATHER NOT TELL. So, when someone click YES, Request[] will call the selected one which is YES. But what if I also want to show that the user did not select NO or the one.

This is the HTML

#### 1)Are you undergraduate or graduate student?

```
        <input id="radio1" name="radioq1" type="radio" value="graduate" />graduate
        <input id="radio2" name="radioq1" type="radio" value="undergraduate" />undergraduate
```

My code behind is

```
info = "You selected <br />=" + Request["radioq1"] + "<br />"
            + "The other options you did not select is " + Request[];
```

Comment: can you share your code.

Comment: I posted the code

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var nonSelectedRadios = [];
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
  if (!radios[i].checked) nonSelectedRadios.push(radios[i].value);
}

console.log(nonSelectedRadios); // ["NO", "I'D RATHER NOT TELL"]
```

That way you'll select all radios that weren't checked.
You haven't posted your entire layout so I don't know the best method for you to get your radioboxes - but it may be better to get all checkboxes with `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Alternatively you could return an array with each radio and whether or not it was checked:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
  results.push({
    value: radios[i].value,
    checked: radios[i].checked
  });
}

console.log(results); 
// [{ value: "YES", checked: true }, { value: "NO", checked: false }, ...]
```